"Laundry mesh bags" or "mesh laundry bags"
Is it "laundry mesh bags" or "mesh laundry bags"? Thank you!

Obviously you've found both versions yourself, so you know they're both in use. And I don't really see any scope for saying the two different sequences refer to different products. Use whichever you like - just don;t go thinking there's some "English Language Committee" passing judgement on the "correct" version here. I don't think the traditional "rpyal order of adjectives" *(opinion size age shape color origin material purpose) is much use here. It's only a guide anyway, but not really in this exact context.

Hm, I didn't know they are both grammatically correct until you pointed it out,  thus the question. That being said, thank you for your explanations ~

To me 'mesh laundry bag' sounds better, and your first link actually has it that way round in its website address.

Via Google, I can find on sale both "clothes peg bags" (bags for clothes pegs) and "linen peg bags" (linen bags for pegs). So there's not a firm rule for any of this.

As you see, both versions are in use, but I much prefer mesh laundry bag, and that way round is way more common.
I think FumbleFingers mentions the order of adjectives, in which material comes before purpose. But a better way to think of it is that "laundry bag" is a compound noun you wouldn't split to fodge an adjective in between.

Yes, I think you've usefully expanded on my comment. Actually, I voted to close as "primarily opinion-based" when I commented, but I'll retract that in a minute. I preceded both mesh bag and laundry bag by the highly specific determiner my in this usage chart where in both cases the adjective is effectively "part of the identity" of the item rather than a way to distinguish it from other contextually relevant bags. Laundry bag dominates.

@FumbleFingers, The question is about the collocation "laundry mesh bag", which ngrams doesn't find a single occurence of.

You misunderstand the point of my chart. Obviously the 3-word collocation "laundry mesh bag" won't occur often enough to show on a usage chart (if it did, the OP probably wouldn't need to ask about it). But what the chart does show is that laundry bag is far more common than mesh bag - especially when preceded by my, which tends to match more of the "domestic" contexts we're interested in here (a mesh bag is more likely to occur in laboratories or manufacturing processes, which we're not interested in here).

Okay, I didn't know it's unnecessary to thank those who are willing to take the time to answer questions on the forum. I also didn't know by doing so it has caused inconvenience to some. I guess I'll stop being polite,
